# Is there any way to receive notification through Push Kit?

Tags: swift, pushkit

I want to receive silent push notification when app is killed in iOS.
So I have implemented Push Kit framework in my app. Is there any way to send notification through push Kit? as FCM console or push try....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM does not support silent push notification.

[Does Firebase Cloud Messaging support VOIP pushkit services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326450/does-firebase-cloud-messaging-support-voip-pushkit-services)

You can try using below php file and terminal command.

---

**Php file**

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):


$deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first silent push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
'content-available'=> 1,
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => 0,
);



// Encode the payload as JSON

$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

---

**Use below commands to create pem file and use it in above code**

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushCert.pem

// Convert .p12 to .pem. Enter your pass pharse which is the same pwd that you have given while creating the .p12 certificate. PEM pass phrase also same as .p12 cert.  
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey1.pem -in pushkey.p12

Enter Import Password:

MAC verified OK

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

// To remove passpharse for the key to access globally. This only solved my stream_socket_client() & certificate capath warnings.
$ openssl rsa -in PushKey1.pem -out PushKey1_Rmv.pem

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:

writing RSA key

// To join the two .pem file into one file:
$ cat PushCert.pem PushKey1_Rmv.pem > ApnsDev.pem
```

[Refer more information](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)

Comment: Will apple accept app if I do not use calling service ??

Comment: Nope, apple will not accept if there is no VOIP feature. Either voip feature has to be there or app has to be in specific category like healthcare, location based or something and prior permission has to be taken from apple.