# How send VoIP push notifications from firebase console?

Tags: swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, voip

How could I send the VoIP notification from the firebase console? I already integrated firebase notification functionality in my iOS development project. Now I am want to work with callKit.

Comment: Firebase does't support VOIP notification for iOS

Comment: does any framework exist that will convert firebase push to VoIP push ?

Comment: Check this answer this might be helpful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061489/is-there-any-way-to-receive-notification-through-push-kit