# How to send bulk push notifications via APNS or Pushkit in IOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, pushkit

I want to send bulk notifications to the Android and IOS users. For Android I am using FCM (with high priority messages, so that to send to killed apps also) but in IOS, I must use pushkit or VOIP push notifications to send the updates event to killed apps also.

I need a FCM subscrptions/topics like concept in IOS so that I just need to send notification to only 2 groups - 1 for Android (FCM subscriptions ) and 1 for IOS.

Problems:

1. I can't find FCM subscription like for IOS in APNS.
2. I can't send Voip APNS via FCM because FCM may not support it as per the comments in the [Does Firebase Cloud Messaging support VOIP pushkit services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326450/does-firebase-cloud-messaging-support-voip-pushkit-services)

Comment: You can use FCM for sending messages to iOS as well

Comment: There is a lot of platforms that support it like http://onesignal.com , or Insider http://mobile.useinsider.com , or using the FCM

Comment: Does it support IOS Voip push in bulk along with android, so that I will create a one single subscription group?