# Does Firebase Support IOS Voip Notifications?

Tags: ios, firebase

Our application is based on MeteorJS and is using Cordova to Generate IOS/Android apps.
We are using the following plugin to support push Notifications with Firebase
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push.
Now we want to implement VoIP push notifications in our app, so my question being:
Does Firebase Support IOS Voip Notifications?
I am seeing conflicting rumors on different sites/pages.
Based on this topic, this was not supported in 2016 (but i see some people posting workarounds?).
[Does Firebase Cloud Messaging support VOIP pushkit services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326450/does-firebase-cloud-messaging-support-voip-pushkit-services).
Also, the plugin specific above, has a voip options to be passed to the API, but will i be able to use it with Firebase?

Thanks a lot for your answers