# Problems not receiving FCM when the counterpart device is in low power mode, or when the background app refresh for the current app is disabled (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently developing a 1:1 call ios application with the other party based on CallKit.
As shown in the payload below, the caller sends a notification to the recipient via the FCM.

```
{
    "to": "FCMTOKEN",
    "priority": "high",
    "data" : {
        "sender": "abc@abc.net",
        "action": "OFFER_CALL",
        "call_type": "audiocall"
    },
    "content_available": true
}
```

If the other party's app is foreground or in the background, the call is connected to receive FCM normally by utilizing Appdelegate's DidReceiveRemoteNotification method.

However, you will not receive FCM if the other person's app is in the following state.

1. Low power mode
2. Background app refresh is disabled
3. App is in Terminated state

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        providerDelegate = ProviderDelegate(callManager: callManager)
       
        
        
        // MARK: - Notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
       
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
```

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if let action = userInfo["action"] as? String {
            self.action = action
        }
        
        switch action {
            
        case "OFFER_CALL":
            displayIncomingCall(uuid: UUID(), handle: self.caller ?? "") { _ in
            }
            
        }

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

1. I assigned the BackgroundTask according to the other party's app status, but as a result, I did not receive the same FCM.

```swift
// AppDelegate
       // MARK: - BGTask
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "myApp.refresh", using: nil) { task in
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
            self.scheduleAppRefresh()
        }
        
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "myApp.processing", using: nil) { task in
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
            self.scheduleBackgroundProcessing()
        }


    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.scheduleAppRefresh()
        self.scheduleBackgroundProcessing()
    }
```

```swift
extension AppDelegate {
 func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "myApp.refresh")

        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1 * 60) // Refresh after 5 minutes.

        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
            print("App refresh task scheduled successfully.")
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh task \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

     func scheduleBackgroundProcessing() {
         let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "myApp.processing")
         request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true // Need to true if your task need to network process. Defaults to false.
         request.requiresExternalPower = true // Need to true if your task requires a device connected to power source. Defaults to false.

         request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1 * 60) // Process after 5 minutes.

         do {
             try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
             print("App backgroundprocessing task scheduled successfully.")
         } catch {
             print("Could not schedule image fetch: (error)")
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a [voip push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326450/does-firebase-cloud-messaging-support-voip-pushkit-services) for voip applications.